# Angular 9 - ngx-cookie-service troubles with path

Tags: angular, cookies, setcookie, angular-cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I'm using **ngx-cookie-service** package to store some data relevant to my application.
I need to save this cookie on the base path `'/'`, so each time I know exactly how to retrieve it.
This cookie of mine needs to be updated and when such happens, the new cookie must be stored in the same path (so in `'/'`). The problem is that **sometimes** when I refresh the page, a new cookie is saved in a new path, so when I try to retrieve it with `this.cookieService.get(cookieName, '/')` it obviously fails. This happens though I explicitly state to use `'/'` as *path*. It doesn't occur always and this cause the debugging even harder.

This is the service where I use cookies

```
const urlParamsCookieName = 'errepiuapp-url-params';

/**
 * This service keeps track of the keys used to retrieve objects from the backend.
 */
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KeyLookupService {

  private _lookupUrlSegments = ['students', 'macro', 'lto', 'sto', 'reports'];
  private _paramsMap$: BehaviorSubject<Map<string, any>>;

  private get paramsMap() {
    return this._paramsMap$.getValue()
  }

  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private router: Router 
  ) {
    if (!this.router.url.includes('auth') && !this.cookieService.check(urlParamsCookieName)) {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    }
    this._paramsMap$ = new BehaviorSubject<Map<string, any>>(
      new Map<string, any>(
        this.cookieService.check(urlParamsCookieName) ? 
          this.getParamsFromCookie().map((value, i) => [this._lookupUrlSegments[i], value]) : 
          this._lookupUrlSegments.map(segment => [segment, null])
      )
    );
    this._paramsMap$.subscribe(_ => {
      this.updateCookie();    //*********** PROBLEM HERE ***********
    });
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(event => {
        this.updateCookie();    //*********** PROBLEM HERE ***********
      })
    ).subscribe();
    this.updateCookie();    //*********** PROBLEM HERE ***********
  }

  addParam(key: string, value: any) {
    this._paramsMap$.next(this.paramsMap.set(key, value));
  }

  public getParams(...lookupKeyword: string[]): Map<string, any> {
    if (lookupKeyword) {
      return new Map<string, any>([...this.paramsMap.keys()]
        .filter(key => lookupKeyword.includes(key))
        .map(key => [key, this.paramsMap.get(key)]));
    }
    return this.paramsMap;
  }

  private getParamsFromCookie(): any[] {
    return Array.from(this.cookieService.get(urlParamsCookieName).split(','));
  }

  private updateCookie() {
    if (this.cookieService.check(urlParamsCookieName)) {
      this.cookieService.delete(urlParamsCookieName, '/');
    }
    this.setCookie();
  }

  private setCookie() {
    this.cookieService.set(urlParamsCookieName, [...this.paramsMap.values()].toLocaleString(), undefined, '/');
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey did you find the solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Laxminarayan no, I eventually opted not to use cookies for that purpose

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: @dc_Bita98 - were you also specifying the path as "/" everywhere you set that cookie? was that still causing the issue? Im experiencing similar issue.  anyone had a solution for this? this is really annoying, and as you OP mentioned, not happening all the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
...
let Future = toInteger(Date.now()) + 5 * 60000;
this.cookies.set('session', data, { 
   expires: Future, 
   path: '/', 
   sameSite: 'Strict' 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I realized that the "extra" cookie that is added brings the same data that the 1st, except the path is different, the path that I defined in my default cookie was **"/"** to cover my routes, but Later when the 2nd cookie was added I realized that my path should be that of this 2nd cookie, since although my initial path is **"/"** (mydomain.com **/**) because I am in a **login**, but as soon as I access my session my path will change to mydomain.com **/admin** /home

At that time my original cookie comes in with **"/"**, but if **I navigate** to a section of my site for example mydomain.com/admin/users

and I press F5, **the new cookie is added with the path in "/admin"**, because indeed I am in another path, I am not in **"/".**

So I left my cookie with the path in **"/admin"**, to make sure that if I reload the page that will be my path even if the sections change, this solved my problem.

Pd:

This is my actual cookie, only I use a 1 cookie for the moment in my site:

**TokenContants.ts**

```
export const COOKIE_KEY = 'current_user';
export const COOKIE_PATH = '/admin';
```

**Auth.service.ts**

```
this.cookieService.set(COOKIE_KEY, JSON.stringify(user), { path: COOKIE_PATH, sameSite: "Strict" });
```

Additional info:

In this case, if you want the cookie to be accessible in all sections of your site, including different paths, you should set the path of the cookie to **"/"** when creating it, as long as your path that you will navigate to is more sections of your site is that **"/"**, but if when you change the section your path changes and you press F5 and it creates a new cookie then you will have to change the path to the path of the cookie that has just been added.

I hope to help you, happy coding.